# Do you need an ESC to run this brushless DC motor with Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, motor, pwm, electronics

This is the motor:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Wholesale-JGA25-2418-8-5-1977-rpm-Electric-Motors-Brushless-Motor-High-Torque-Speed-Controlled-DC/32360228129.html

I'm hooking it up to the arduino as described and giving the PWM outputpin analogWrite functions, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It has an ESC built in.

You just provide power and a PWM signal, and optionally a direction signal.

To test:

1. Connect red to +12V.
2. Connect black to 12V GND and to Arduino GND
3. Connect white to D5
4. `analogWrite(5, 128)`;

Comment: Stupid question, but why does the motors have to connect to Arduino GND as well as the 12V GND?

Comment: @Ary https://majenko.co.uk/blog/importance-sharing-grounds